# overwriting instead of writing to a plist-cocoa

Tags: cocoa, plist

I have created a method to write data to a plist.

```
- (void)writeToPListUserType:(NSString *)type 
                   andUserID:(NSString *)usid 
                andFirstName:(NSString *)fname 
                 andLastName:(NSString *)lname 
                 andPassword:(NSString *)pwd{

    NSMutableDictionary *userDetails = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [userDetails setObject:fname forKey:@"firstName"];
    [userDetails setObject:lname forKey:@"lastName"];
    [userDetails setObject:pwd forKey:@"password"];

    NSMutableDictionary *userIDKey = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [userIDKey setObject:userDetails forKey:usid];

    [userCredentials setObject:userIDKey forKey:type];
    [userIDKey release];
    [userDetails release];

    NSString *error;

    NSString *rootPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
                 (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *plistPath = [rootPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:
                                                     @"userCredentials.plist"];

    NSData *plistData = [NSPropertyListSerialization
                                           dataFromPropertyList:userCredentials
                                            format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0
                                                      errorDescription:&error];

    [plistData writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];
}
```

I am able to write new data to the plist. However, when the new data is written, the old data is no longer there. In other words, the method is overwriting my plist.
Please tell me what is wrong with the method... :(

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Instead of `[[OBJECT alloc] init];`, you can use `[OBJECT new];` -- same result, fewer characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this line:

```
code>[userCredentials setObject:userIDKey forKey:type];
```

you are overwriting the existing "userCredentials" "type" key (I don't see it is newly allocated in the method) with new data.

So the userCredentials, which I suppose is a mutable dictionary created elsewhere, is overwritten with the new data.

Comment: YES!!! u r absolutely right! so silly mistake on my part...anyways..Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 1):

1) read the plist from disk

2) create a mutable in memory copy

3) modify the (in memory) plist

4) overwrite the file you read, using the in memory plist

Comment: Well i guess that is exectly what i did! Can u please elaborate as to where my mistake is?

Comment: @Sahitya Tarumani your example is incomplete. you may have missed one or more of the four steps. which steps you missed specifically (and why), is impossible for me to determine based on the current example.

Comment: in other words: you'll have to provide a complete example so we can attempt to help you in a reasonable amount of time, without guesswork.